# Drupal Database updates loop

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I keep on getting an error in the Status report

> Database updates  Out of date
>   Some modules have database schema updates to install. 
>   You should run the database update script immediately.

Which I do, which tells there are no updates, but then the Status Report keeps on saying that I need to update.

Comment: Have you cleared cache?

Comment: use command line :  drush updb -y && drush cc all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command line :

```
drush updb -y && drush cc all
```

*drush upbd -y* <= will execute all of pending updates in .intall files

*drush cc all* <= clear all cache